# change MaterialYou /Material3 Colors on lower SDK versions

Tags: android, material-you

Recenntly I switched to material3 theming. All are perfect on Android 12 devices. But when it comes to lower SDK versions there a default light blue/purple color which cannot be changed. But we can change this color manually by defining the material colors on the style.xml files. So is there a way we can change these Dynamic colors on lower android versions programatically. I mean can we generate all the dynamic color variants and apply them on lower android versions?